# Twilio call autodisconnect

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

I am making browser to browser call, after successfully call establishment, the call disconnects automatically. The receiver isn't getting incoming function executed. Can anyone help me out?

```
Twilio.Device.setup(token, { debug : true});

Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
    console.log("Client '' is ready");
    //! Ready
});

Twilio.Device.error(function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);

});

Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) {
    console.log("Successfully established call");
});

Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {  
    console.log("From:" + conn.parameters.From);
    console.log("To:" + conn.parameters.To);
    console.log("Call ended");

});

Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
    console.log("Incoming connection from " + conn.parameters.From);
        // accept the incoming connection and start two-way audio

        conn.accept();

});

function call(id) {
    console.log('calling started! to ' + id);
    callto = id;
    params = {"client": id};
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);

}
```

I am using socket to connect the callers! When a second user comes into scene, the call is made to the receiver by the sender. The incoming function is not working in receiver side.

Console Log:

```
[Device] Setting up PStream
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[WSTransport] Opening socket
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[WSTransport] attempting to connect
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Device] Registering to eventStream with url: wss://matrix.twilio.com/2012-02-09/?AccessToken=eyJ&feature=publishPresence
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Matrix] Attempting to connect to wss://matrix.twilio.com/2012-02-09/?AccessToken=eyJ&feature=publishPresence...
twilio.min.js (line 58)

[WSTransport] Socket opened
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Matrix] Socket opened... sending ready signal
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Device] Stream is ready
twilio.min.js (line 58)
Client '' is ready
test (line 3718)
FIREBASE WARNING:
calling to user 12232343
test (line 3749)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
Successfully established call
test (line 3728)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "connected"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Connection] Disconnecting...
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
From:undefined
test (line 3733)
To:undefined
test (line 3734)
Call ended
test (line 3735)
calling started! to 12122323
test (line 3749)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "stable"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
Successfully established call
test (line 3728)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "checking"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "connected"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Connection] Received HANGUP from gateway
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Connection] Disconnecting...
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
[Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
twilio.min.js (line 58)
From:undefined
test (line 3733)
To:undefined
test (line 3734)
Call ended
```

At the other side of the client:

```
    The value "0.6;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
   test:5 The value "0.5;" for key "minimum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix.
   test:5 The key "maximum-scale:0.7;" is not recognized and ignored.
   test:5 Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.
   test:1845 Client '' is ready
    firebase.js:36 FIREBASE WARNING:
```

Comment: Could you share the console log from a call that acts this way? Thanks!

Comment: @philnash I have added console for the twilio

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. The end of the call there shows that the connection closed with undefined parameters for From and To, which is strange. Do you have the console log from the other side of the call?

Comment: console log of the other side of the client, would like to mention we are using ubuntu and recently converted website to https. Earlier it worked fine in firefox and chrome but due to non-support of http support in chrome, we had to make our site secure. Thanks @philnash

Comment: So does the other side never receive the incoming call?

Comment: No it doesn't receive incoming call, that is my issue !

Comment: Ah right, sorry! Does your TwiML application receive a request from Twilio when you initiate the call?

Comment: Like we have not used any TwiML application to receive a request after making the call. Usually the other side receive a call with ring and he needed to accept the call by approving the microphone permission. To establish a connection between we have used Firebase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101182/discussion-between-rahul-varma-and-philnash).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! As the site was secure, made a new TwiML application with new request url to [receive](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/incoming-calls) and [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/client/outgoing-calls) via the browser. Thanks to @philnash for helping me sort out the issue